# is_defined constexpr function

Tags: c++11, c++14, constexpr

I need to know whether NDEBUG is defined when specifying the noexcept specifier. I was thinking along the lines of this constexpr function:

```
constexpr inline bool is_defined() noexcept
{
  return false;
}

constexpr inline bool is_defined(int) noexcept
{
  return true;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
void f() noexcept(is_defined(NDEBUG))
{
  // blah, blah
}
```

Does the standard library or the language already provide a facility for this so that I won't be reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in `NDEBUG`, this is equivalent to testing whether `assert()` evaluates it's argument or not. In that case, you can use:

```
void f() noexcept(noexcept(assert((throw true,true))))
{
    // ...
}
```

This is, of course, not necessarily an improvement :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use `#ifdef`?

```
#ifdef  NDEBUG
using is_ndebug = std::true_type;
#else
using is_ndebug = std::false_type;
#endif

void f() noexcept(is_ndebug{}) {
  // blah, blah
}
```

or a myriad of other similar ways:  A `constexpr` function returning `bool` or `std::true_type` (conditionally).  A `static` variable of one of two types.  A traits class that takes an enum which lists various `#define` token-equivalents (`eNDEBUG` etc) which can be specialized for each such token it has support for, and generates errors if there is no such support.  Using `typedef` instead of `using` (if your compiler has flaky support for using, I'm looking at you MSVC2013).  I'm sure there can be others.

Comment: There are a myriad of ways, but not all of them work, because of compiler bugs. It's gcc: error `noexcept (<uninstantiated>)' has a different exception specifier`